# Expose struct fields on CustomEditor

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am using a struct to save all the tweakable variables and I am writing a customer editor for the designer to tweak them.

Because the variable contained by the struct is always changing. So I am wondering if it is possible to expose a struct and its fields on a customer editor.

To clarify me, here are some sample code.

**ScriptA:**

```
[Serializable]
public struct Settings
{
    public float boo;
    public float foo;
    public int baz;
}

public Settings settings {get;set;}
//this one will be exposed but i don't want to use a public field
public Settings settings2;
```

**ScriptAEditor:**

```
public override void OnInspectorGUI(){
        //how to expose `ScriptA.settings` so the user can tweak its field.

       //i can also do a bunch of  EditorGUILayout.IntField and EditorGUILayout.FloatField but it is too manual.
 }
```

Comment: Why don't you simply : `[SerializeField] private Settings settings2;` If you want a custom editor, you may need [`EditorGUILayout.ObjectField`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorGUILayout.ObjectField.html)

Comment: @Hellium I didn't know I can serialize private field?!